# Store a global counter in DB? Whats another option?

Tags: asp.net, counter, save

I need to store 2 values (counters) for my ASP.NET web app. The counters always grow, they should never return to 0. So one option would be to save them in DB, what other options do I have, because storing them in a table seems disproportionate? Session is not an option because the counters have to survive app restarts.

Thanks :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of the counters? Knowing this will help us give an answer that fits your needs.

Comment: Those counters go to a file which is created from the web app...for each object (some custom thing we have) which is written to the file, they are increased in a certain way. This exported file is read by some 3rd party app on the customer side.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the counts in a DB table sounds perfectly appropriate here.

The other options which come to mind are to use a file, which would not be very reliable ACID wise, or memory, using something like memcache, which would not survive a system reboot.

Don't worry about using a DB table. It will hardly take up any storage space or incur any significant overhead unless they are being written to very frequently. If that's the case, please add more info and we may be able to propose other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If these counters are rarely updated, and can be machine dependent (you're not in a cluster) then I'd use something simple, like writing their values to a Settings file. Keep in mind you'll have to cope with multi-threading.

If there's a lot of access to the counters, store them in a database.

Answer (score -1):

Save them in a file. Fastest way.

Comment: So, you think file IO is always faster than network IO? And multi threaded access will not be a problem?

Comment: @Oded, I agree, in big apps with a lot of IO, it's more reasonable to leave any persistence to the database. When it comes to small to medium apps, a file is an alternative, sometimes better. After all, there's a big difference between sending a command and getting a result set via the network, and building up queues for a local file IO.